# Can Avodah Zarah acquire a state of Hekdesh?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, beis-hamikdash, hekdesh, issurei-hanaa

What's the Halachic status of Avodah Zarah which someone *somehow* pronounced Hekdesh (even accidentally, like choosing the wrong jug of oil)? Does the Avodah Zarah accept Hekdesh?

If it *can* become Hekdesh, can it still be destroyed? Can the value be swapped and exchanged for money, and then be thrown into the Dead Sea? Or is this considered Hana'ah, and one may not benefit monetarily from it?

Comment: What value is there to Avoda Zara?

Comment: For example, if the Mona Lisa painting was worshipped. And someone rich enough bought it and tried making it Hekdesh. @DoubleAA

Comment: Once he worshipped it it would become worthless since there's nothing anyone could use it for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rashi in Gittin 12b says Hekdesh can only work on something that is worth a *shave Pruta*:

> אין הקדש חל על פחות משוה פרוטה

The Ramban argues Hekdesh can work on something worth *less* than a *shave pruta* but it needs to be tangeble and worth something:

> אם היה אותו ממון בעין והקדישו אפילו אפחות משוה פרוטה נמי אחילי.

avoda zara is considerred not tangeble and as if it has been destroyed  hence not worth anything as it says in Chullin 89b:

> עבודת כוכבים כתותי מכתת שיעורא

So everyone agrees Hekdesh would not work on Avoda Zara.